# Insert value form previous cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am using Pandas to manipulate a table. I need to replace repeating fields of '....' with the value previous

| Code |
| --- |
| ABC |
| .... |
| .... |
| .... |
| 123 |
| .... |
| .... |
| .... |

Should be

| Code |
| --- |
| ABC |
| ABC |
| ABC |
| ABC |
| 123 |
| 123 |
| 123 |
| 123 |

I think is something like df['Code'] == df['Code'].shift().fillna(-1) but cant work out how to do it row by row (9000 rows)

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `....`to missing values `NaN`s and then forward filling previous no missing values:

```
df['Code'] = df['Code'].replace('....', np.nan).ffill()
```

EDIT:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

means in some lines before is used filtering, if you modify values in `df` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df1`), and that Pandas does warning:

```
df = df1[df1['col'] == 1]

df['Code'] = df['Code'].replace('....', np.nan).ffill()
```

Solution is use [`DataFrame.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
df = df1[df1['col'] == 1].copy()

df['Code'] = df['Code'].replace('....', np.nan).ffill()
```

Comment: Thank you - however it errors with A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Thank you - perfect

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

```
df['Code'].replace('....',method='ffill',inplace=True)
```

`method` argument will help you do your work instead of calling `ffill()` separately